# simplex algorithm help for continuing in case of $\lambda \equiv 0$

Tags: optimization, algorithms, linear-programming

Is it possible that while the simplex algorithm is working, we get a lambda  $$ (Ax < b, \max c^T x )$$  $$ \lambda_B = c^T A^{-1}_B $$

with only zeros in it ? if so what does it would represent/ mean ? I think that if there is one zero, that means that the solution has one degree of freedom, so a face of degree 1 is a solution.

I'm doubtfull why in the algorithm, we allow lambda to be equal to 0 at some entries.

Comment: From the way it is written, I do not think so. That would mean that either $c=0$ (but the initial problem would be of no interest), either that $A^{-1}_B$ is not invertible ($ker \neq \{0\}$), but this contradicts the fast that by construction it is the inverse of $A_B$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of zeros represents indeed the number of dimension of the optimal solution. I had a problem within my resolution of the problem, that's why I got a $$ \lambda \equiv 0 $$
In any other case, that shoudln't be the case, unless the whole initial set is a solution to the problem .

E.G. :
an optimisation problem where the objective function is $$ \min \textbf{0} \cdot c^t  $$